# Clique-width of a tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have to prove that the clique-width of a tree is not greater that 3, without using the theorem which connects the tree-width and clique-width. I have to show that it's enough to construct any tree using 3-expression.

I tried to do it with induction but I wasn't succesfull. The thing is that I easily understoon for paths and cycles because I know their shape, but trees aren't that unique when it comes to their construction. Any hints on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a set $L$ of $3$ labels, which we can use in a $3$ expression to construct the tree $T$.  Recall that we are allowed to take the disjoint union of two labeled graphs in the operations allowed for clique-width.

We will prove a slightly stronger statement:
let $r$ be any vertex of $T$ and let $a,b \in L$ with $a \neq b$.  Then $T$ can be constructed from a $3$-expression such that $r$ is labeled $a$, and every other vertex is labeled $b$.

This can be proved by induction.  As a base case, if $T$ has only one vertex, this is trivial.  Assume $T$ has at least two vertices.  Let $c$ be the label of $L$ distinct from $a$ and $b$, and let $s$ be a neighbor of $r$ in $T$.
By removing the $rs$ edge, two trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ are obtained.

I actually had the rest of the proof written, but I see you're asking for hints rather than an answer.
This should get you started, as you can use induction to construct $T_1$ and $T_2$ and join them together to get the desired properties.